# Jhipster reset email

Tags: jhipster

1. Jhipster front end application can be accessible  using http://localhost:9000
2. Jhipster back end application can be accessible using http://loclahost:8080
3. when i create new user then it sends email to password reset link to email
   http://localhost:9000/reset/finish?key=02729664541522595759.
4. when I click on this link then getting your request can not be processed
5. I am able to see console log warning message
   fixurl.js:222 A parser-blocking, cross site (i.e. different eTLD+1) script, https://linkhelp.clients.google.com/tbproxy/lh/wm?sourceid=wm&url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9000%2Ftest&hl=en&site=localhost%3A9000&error=http404&js=true, is invoked via document.write. The network request for this script MAY be blocked by the browser in this or a future page load due to poor network connectivity. If blocked in this page load, it will be confirmed in a subsequent console message. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5718547946799104 for more details.

Comment: If your server and client are separate, try the changes in https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/9860/files which will be in the next release

Comment: we are using hash (#) in urls. So when i included # in basw-url it is working.mail: # specific JHipster mail property, for standard properties see MailProperties
    base-url: http://localhost:9000/#. Now it works